# What are the original components to a 1953 Schwinn Paramount?

Tags: road-bike, parts

I have a 1953 Schwinn Paramount that I inherited and have been riding as my daily commuter.  I think most everything is original, but am not sure. Where can I find out what the original components should be, and any idea of its value?

Answer (score 2):

The Schwinn Paramount was a special machine, as [Sheldon Brown describes](http://sheldonbrown.com/chicago-schwinns.html). I cannot tell you what components it had, because it seems that they were [custom built to order only](http://schwinncruisers.com/catalogs/1953.html#paramount-boys).

Maybe the people at the [Schwinn Paramount Registry](http://www.kurtkaminer.com/TH_paramountregistry.html) can help more.

Looks like it's valuable. Look after it.